# How do I ensure a smooth transition for geom_segment() using gganimate?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, gganimate

I am trying to plot a histogram with a mean vertical line for each year in the data provided . The data can be found [here](https://github.com/adhok/data_sources_new/blob/main/speed.RDS)

The code is as follows

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data_speed <- readRDS("speed.RDS")
animated_histogram <- data_speed %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fastestLapSpeed)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "#ff1801") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = avg_speed, xend = avg_speed, y = 0, yend = Inf),
               color = "blue", size = 1, linetype = "") +
  labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}") +
  transition_time(year) +
  ease_aes('linear')

animate(animated_histogram, fps = 30, duration = 10, width = 500, height = 250)
```

Based on the above code , I get the following plot.

[image]

How do I ensure that the vertical mean line (blue dashed line) transitions smoothly without any breaks in between?

The library versions are as follows

```
> packageVersion("gganimate")
[1] ‘1.0.8’
> packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘3.4.2’
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.1.2’
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is smooth enough. First, I would suggest to use a `geom_vline`  instead of a `geom_segment`. Second, instead of adding a segment or vline for *each row* of your data as you do I use a summarized dataset for the `geom_vline` which contains one row per year:

```r
library(gganimate)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".RDS")

download.file("https://github.com/adhok/data_sources_new/raw/main/speed.RDS", tmp)

data_speed <- readRDS(tmp)

data_speed_avg <- data_speed |>
  summarise(fastestLapSpeed = mean(fastestLapSpeed), .by = year)

ggplot(data_speed, aes(x = fastestLapSpeed)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "#ff1801") +
  geom_vline(
    data = data_speed_avg, aes(xintercept = fastestLapSpeed),
    color = "blue", linewidth = 1
  ) +
  labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}") +
  transition_time(year) +
  ease_aes("linear")
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]